# Total pairs of binary strings permuted from $n-m$ $1$s and $m$ $0$s so that all initial substrings of $(1)$ have more $0$s than that of $(2)$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinatorics-on-words

The length of the two original binary strings is $n$ with $m$ zeros and $n-m$ ones.

Let the two initial sub-strings (*ie.* beginning from index $0$ of the string and ending at any index **except the final**) be $S(1)$ and $S(2)$.

$S(1)$ must **always** have more zeros than $S(2)$, whatever the length of the sub-string.

Take for example -

$(1) - 00010111$

$(2) - 10110100$

**Initial Substrings**

**length = $1$**

"0" > "1"

**length = $2$**

"00" > "10"

**length = $3$**

"000" > "101" ...and so on.

$(1)$ and $(2)$ satisfy this requirement (each $S(1)$ has more zeros than $S(2)$), so $(1),(2)$ is one of the pairs in the count.

Find the total pairs of strings each permuted from n-m ones and m zeros such that the restriction placed is satisfied.

I really don't know how I should proceed. Hints please.

Comment: Can you clarify what $S(1)$ and $S(2)$ are? I don't understand your explanation.

Comment: @DerekLuna They are both initial substrings. For example - "000" is an initial substring of "0001101".

Comment: Your example is in terms of a pair of strings, while the question asks to count strings, not pairs of strings.  Shouldn't it be the number of strings that any prefix has more (does equality count?) $0$s than $1$s.  Your first string would satisfy this, but the second would not.

Comment: @RossMillikan I hope the edit clears some things